# How do I change query parameters in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I'm writing an action handler in `route:application`:

```
actions: {
  changeFoo(foo) {
    // I want to change the fooId queryParam to foo.get('id')
  }
}
```

The problem is that the only documented ways I can find to change the query params are `transitionTo('some.route', someModel, { queryParams: { ... } }` and the `replaceWith` version of the same. But I'm in `route:application`, so I don't know the current route's name. That means I don't know what the first argument to `transitionTo` would be.

Is there another way to get the URL to become `?fooId=123`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need current route name. You can just do 'transitionTo({queryParams: { foo: 123 })'. The router will apply it to the correct route.

Comment: Yep, you're right: this works. It's not documented, but used internally by Ember.

Comment: It's documented in the [guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/routing/query-params/#toc_transitionto) and [api docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_transitionTo)

Answer (score 1):

From **controller:application** you can set the query param `foo` like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['foo'],

  actions: {
    updateMyQueryParam() {
      this.set('foo', 'hello');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried doing the following from my route action, but it didn't take: `this.controllerFor('application').set('foo', 123);`

Comment: Here is the same code with the action on the route: https://github.com/max/ember-query-params/commit/afbe8e9091be879d53f3b54dcca6735ba13d80ac What version of Ember are you running?