# How do I set an Ember query-parameter on the first transition?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router, ember-query-params

This is a follow-on to [#35192211](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35192211/1190)

I have a query-param, say `'locale'`. When the user first loads the application, if they haven't specified a `?locale=...`, then I'd like to detect one and immediately set the query-parameter. (This way, if they share the URL, others will see exactly what they're seeing. If you think this is a bad idea for locales, imagine another contextual query parameter like `account`.)

So, if the user navigates directly to `/foo/bar?locale=es`, then they stay there. If they navigate to `/foo/bar`, then the URL immediately switches to `/foo/bar?locale=en` and it renders the foo page.

#### Attempt 1

```
beforeModel(transition) {
  if (transition.queryParams.locale == null) {
    return this.transitionTo({ queryParams: { locale: 'en' } });
  }
}
```

This does nothing. At the end of the transition, the URL has no `?locale=en`.

#### Attempt 2

```
beforeModel(transition) {
  if (transition.queryParams.locale == null) {
    this.send('switchLocale', 'en');
  }
},
actions: {
  switchLocale(locale) {
    this.controllerFor('application').set('locale', locale);
    this.refresh();
  }
}
```

This throws the following exception:

> Error while processing route: foo.bar Can't trigger action 'switchLocale' because your app hasn't finished transitioning into its first route. To trigger an action on destination routes during a transition, you can call `.send()` on the `Transition` object passed to the `model/beforeModel/afterModel` hooks.

#### Attempt 3

Same as (2), but using `transition.send('switchLocale', 'en')`.

This prevents the error, but we're back to it accomplishing nothing.

Comment: Is query param name `location` or `locale`?

Comment: locale. Typo when I wrote this up. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: In which file you use this `beforeModel` methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so seems I have met both requirements:

> So, if the user navigates directly to /foo/bar?locale=es, then they
>   stay there. If they navigate to /foo/bar, then the URL immediately
>   switches to /foo/bar?locale=en and it renders the foo page.

Basically I'm using `Ember.run.next` in `beforeModel`:

```
beforeModel(transition) {
  if (transition.queryParams.locale == null) {
    Ember.run.next(() => transition.send('switchLocale', 'en'));
  }
},
```

Check [working demo](https://ember-twiddle.com/02ea221e1ee3c5cb662c?openFiles=router.js%2Capplication.template.hbs&route=%2Ffoo%2Fbar%3Flocale%3Des).

Comment: Nice workaround! It looks like Ember does something later in the first run-loop that overrides the changes.